# Vertx is not available in Quarkus vertx munity web client extesions

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, smallrye

I tried to test the reactive web client provided by vertx munity web client.

I followed the official guide [Quarkus - Getting Started with Reactive](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive).

And added the following in dependencies.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But when I injected `Vertx` as mentioned in the article, and got the CDI unsatisfied dependency exception. `Vertx` is not available.

```sh
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: com.example.PostResourceClient#vertx
```

The complete codes are [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/tree/master/restclient-vertx-munity).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the `io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx` dependency to your POM to activate the Vertx extension. `io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web-client` is an external dependency that does not activate any extension.